# How to find a parameter name from a word document, and then extract / edit the parameter value in the word/txt document

Tags: java

I made a basic game recently while learning java, and would like to implement a way to store/overwrite scores for the game. For example, if "John" played the game, and ended with a score of 12, I would like him to be able to type in "John" to see if the score is his personal best. Then, if "Mary" was to play, and receive a score of 8, she could type "Mary" and her score would be saved.

For this question, I am uninterested in -how- the information is displayed (System.out.println is fine) and I am primarily concerned with the code which parses through and changes the txt document given a name input. For simplicity, we can say that a score is simply input into the console, then you enter your name and see/edit if the score beats that name's high score.

The code would need to parse through the document to first see if "name" existed in the record. Then, it would either add ["name " + score] to the list if the name was not in the record or check the new score against the person's high score, changing it if applicable. Finally, it would output the player's high score.

For example, the file contains:

```
Tim 4
John 8
Sue 12
Jack 314
```

Scenario 1: John plays, ends with a score of 12, and the code finds John's high score, changes it, and outputs that he beat his high score (now 12).

Scenario 2: Mary plays, scores 8, and her name is added to the end of the list with her score. The code then outputs that her high score is 8.

Scenario 3: Sue plays, scores a 7, and the system checks the scores, outputting that her high score remains at 12.
...
If there is a better way to write/store/reference such information (which are basically integer perameters), I am interested in that as well, but a txt or word document that lists the high scores is the best I've thought up.

(Side question: Given the list/names of scores, what about code that checks each score for the overall high score?)

Comment: it is homework, isn't it?

Comment: Ha ha. No, it's a personal project. ('Bonus / side question' was another way of saying 'related but not main question.')